# Comma separated values to List

Tags: asp.net

I have a List like,

Class Traking {
public sting TrackID {get;set}
public sting AlertID {get;set} // Comma separated Values
}

```
            TrackID    AlertID
            1001       101,102,103
            1002       201,202,203
            1003       301,302,303
```

AlertID having comma seperated values, Using Linq convet to Like this

```
           TrackID   AlertID
           1001       101
           1001       102
           1001       103
           1002       201
           1002       202
           1002       203
           1003       301
           1003       302
           1003       303
```

Ex:
 [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)
- This done from SQL, the same way need to do in LinQ

I hope understand my problem

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What are you trying to do, and what are you unable to do?

Comment: You want to convert a list of `Traking` objects into an HTML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object looks like this:

```
class Traking 
{
    public string TrackID {get;set;}
    public string AlertID {get;set;} // Comma separated Values
}
```

And your list looks like this:

```
var ls=new List<Traking>
    {
        new Traking(){TrackID = "1001",AlertID = "101,102,103"},
        new Traking(){TrackID = "1002",AlertID = "201,202,203"},
        new Traking(){TrackID = "1003",AlertID = "301,302,303"},
    };
```

Then you can do this:

```
var result= ls.SelectMany (l => l.AlertID.Split(',').Select (s =>new Traking()
    {
        TrackID=l.TrackID,
        AlertID=s
    } )).ToList()
```

To get this output:

```
TrackID    AlertID
1001       101 
1001       102 
1001       103 
1002       201 
1002       202 
1002       203 
1003       301 
1003       302 
1003       303
```